# vb.net weird extension method behaviour?

Tags: vb.net, extension-methods

Here's a little something I discovered in vb.net which I cannot figure out, I've just got a form with a treeview on it and then the following:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    treeTest.Nodes.Add("a")
    treeTest.Nodes(0).Test()
End Sub
```

Test is an extension method:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Public Module ExtModule
    <Extension()>
    Public Sub Test(ByRef node As TreeNode)
    End Sub
End Module
```

If I use ByRef then my treeview looks like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zasN.png]

And with ByVal I get:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBeVS.png]

This seems totally backwards, if I'm simply sending a reference why is the node appearing twice, while if I make a copy it only appears once?

Comment: Um, your Test method doesn't actually *do* anything at the moment, which makes it hard to understand your question. Also, I suspect you may misunderstand what `ByRef` actually means...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: The OP is RIGHT. I used the same code to test (with an EMPTY extension method) and by just calling the method as shown by the poster, a second node is added. Changing to _ByVal_ and the second node is not created ... ???

Comment: @igrimpe: I suspect this is something odd about the way that VB handles pass-by-reference. (In C#, you can't even declare an extension method with a `ref` parameter.) I still think the OP doesn't understand what `ByRef` means though :)

Comment: @igrimpe: Hmm... I'm struggling to reproduce this with a short but complete program. I wonder whether it's version-specific...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Just use the OP's code on a single form with a treeview

Tested in VS2012

Comment: @JonSkeet: I am also able to reproduce under VS2010. Weird...

Comment: @igrimpe: Interesting - it seems to happen when invoked during Form.Load, but not *before* Load is called. (I'm going to convert it to C# for my own sanity...)

Comment: [This is interesting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2007/01/18/extension-methods-part-3.aspx). `X has magically become null. How did this happen?` Seems to be another side effect of the same problem.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I thought ByRef sent a reference of the object, and ByVal created a copy of the object.  So if I had a function which changed x when ByRef was used x would be changed in the function that called it.

Comment: @4285: ByVal sends a reference for reference types, and value for value types.

Comment: @4285: No, `ByVal` *doesn't* send a "copy of the object". You need to understand that the value of any expression of a reference type is already just a reference, not an object. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html for a C# view of things which should help somewhat - basically `ref` in C# is roughly equivalent to `ByRef`, and the default is equivalent to `ByVal`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I've worked out *some* of what's going on.

It's got relatively little to do with extension methods per se. It's more about how VB handles `ByRef` in general, and some odd behaviour of `TreeView.Nodes` by the looks of it.

In particular, you'll get the *exact* same behaviour if you change this:

```
treeTest.Nodes(0).Test()
```

to:

```
ExtModule.Test(treeTest.Nodes(0))
```

... even if you remove the `ExtensionAttribute`.

Here's some C# code which demonstrates the same effect, without using `ref` parameters or extension methods at all:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TreeView tree = new TreeView { Nodes = { "a" } };
        Form form = new Form { Controls = { tree } };
        form.Load += delegate {
            TreeNode node = tree.Nodes[0];
            tree.Nodes[0] = node;
        };
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

The important lines are these ones:

```
TreeNode node = tree.Nodes[0];
tree.Nodes[0] = node;
```

When your empty extension method has a `ByRef` parameter, your code is equivalent to the above C# code - because VB fakes "real" `ByRef` behaviour by using a temporary variable and then assigning back to the original property.

When your empty extension method has a `ByVal` parameter, your code is just equivalent to:

```
TreeNode node = tree.Nodes[0];
// Do nothing
```

... and that *doesn't* create a second node.

Comment: Isn't it a bug in VB? I mean self-assignment should not cause such issues normally.

Comment: @Neolisk: Well, this is how VB handles `ByRef` parameters. I don't like it personally, but it's the designed behaviour. It looks more like a bug in `TreeNodeCollection` to me, given the C# code.

Comment: You are probably right, btw, here is a TL;DR version of your post: `treeTest.Nodes(0) = treeTest.Nodes(0)` creates another node, which it should not. Hence all the problems. Thanks for digging it up. +1

Comment: @Hans Passant: I dont think your link fits to THIS problem. The Error lies in the TreeView and can be shown with C# as `Jon Skeet` proved. The ByRef behavior just made this error (bug? strange behaviour?) visible, but does not cause it.

Comment: Yes, it is clearly a `TreeView` related problem and not a VB or extension method related problem. My tests (please see my answer) confirm what Jon Skeet says.

Answer (score 2):

I compiled a little VB example and decompiled it as C# code with Reflector. This is what I got:

```
treeView.Nodes.Add("a");
TreeNodeCollection VB$t_ref$S0 = treeView.Nodes;
int VB$t_i4$S0 = 0;
TreeNode VB$t_ref$S1 = VB$t_ref$S0[VB$t_i4$S0];
ref VB$t_ref$S1.Test();
VB$t_ref$S0[VB$t_i4$S0] = VB$t_ref$S1;
```

It does not compile. Therefore I did another test

```
treeView1.Nodes.Add("a");
treeView1.Nodes[0] = treeView1.Nodes[0];
treeView1.Nodes[0] = treeView1.Nodes[0];
treeView1.Nodes[0] = treeView1.Nodes[0];
```

Each assignment to the `Nodes` collection duplicates the node visually; however, the node count remains `1`. This is clearly an error in the behavior of `TreeView`.

Note: Apparently VB allows the first parameter of an extension method to be by reference. This is awkward and can lead to much unexpected behavior. My advice: Don't use `ByRef` here!

Comment: +1. Interesting find. I would not expect `Nodes.Count` to remain as 1.